# JSON object returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, json

I am receiving a JSON object from a http call and I am trying to extract values from it. 
JSON object contains:

```
data:{"userid":"007", "role":"spy"}
```

I use the following code to assign **role** property to another variable followed by some console log checks:

```
    currentUserRole = data.role;    
    console.log("type of data: "+typeof(data));
    console.log("data: "+JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log("user role: "+currentUserRole);
```

The logs produce:

```
type of data: object
data: [{"userid":"007", "role":"spy"}]
user role: undefined
```

Also I tried another method of assignment:

```
currentUserRole = data['role'];
```

But currentUserRole remains **undefined**. How can I set a property of a JSON object to a variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(data)` clearly shows that `data` is an **array** with one element, an **object**.

Comment: FYI: JSON *is a string*. You can't set properties on it. This doesn't have anything to do with JSON.

Comment: ^ [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @FelixKling: +1 on the JSON object article

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the second line of your log (the call to `JSON.stringify()`), your `data` is actually an *array* of objects:

```
[{"userid":"007", "role":"spy"}]
```

If it was an object as you are expecting, it would look like this:

```
{"userid":"007", "role":"spy"}
```

(the difference is subtle, but notice the missing square brackets)

Try this:

```
currentUserRole = data[0].role;
```

Obviously in production-ready code, you probably need to do some extra sanity checking to ensure that `data` is in fact an array containing at least one element.

Answer (score 0):

It is a list. Try `data[0].role`

Comment: Hiya, I know this seems obvious to you, but don't forget that total n00bs will probably stumble across your solution at some future time. Can you give a brief explanation for why this solution works (in this case something about it being an object embedded in an array and needing to index into it first)? For The Children ;)

Comment: ofcourse. but now that someone else gave a good answer, I would leave it at that. Will do it in my later replies