# How to read through [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I am reading a list that has the following structure:

```
export interface ISaleEntity {
    id: number;
    dateCreated: Date,
    amount:number,
    type:string,
    description:string
  }
```

My api is returning the following data:

> payments: Array(2) 0: {Id: 1, Type: "DEBIT", Description: "Sale
>   1", Amount: 5000, DateCreated: "06/18/2018 00:00:00"} 1: {Id: 2, Type:
>   "CREDIT", Description: "Sale1", Amount: 4200, DateCreated: "06/20/2018
>   00:00:00"}

Since I am using transcript, I do

```
 const payments: ISaleEntity [] = response.data.payments;



private renderData(payments: ISaleEntity[]) {
    return (
      <div>
        {payments.length}
        {payments.forEach(element => 
       // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
       console.log("element" + element)

        // <span>{element.description}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In console, element is [object Object].

How can I read the loop through JSON object properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var elements=[{Id: 1, Type: "DEBIT", Description: "Sale 1", Amount: 5000, DateCreated: "06/18/2018 00:00:00"} ,{Id: 2, Type: "CREDIT", Description: "Sale1", Amount: 4200, DateCreated: "06/20/2018 00:00:00"}]

elements.forEach(function(elem){
  console.log(elem);
  console.log(elem.Description)
})

console.log(elements[0].Description)
```

If you want to concatenate with `string` just use

```
console.log("element" + JSON.stringify(element)).
```

`+ element` coerces the `object element` into a `string`, which is just `[object Object]`

`console.log` is an overloaded function that accepts a list of parameters that are either passed by copy (string|number|boolean) or by reference (everything else).

Comment: {payments.length} is 2.  Why is element.description undefined in the following?
 {payments.forEach(element => 
          
         <span>{element.description}</span>
        )}

Comment: @jupitersailormoon see the edits how to iterate over array in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it as another argument to `console.log`:

```
console.log("element", element);
```

Comment: What do you mean @jupitersailormoon?

Comment: This also helped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507807/json-object-returns-undefined-value